# Evaluate following limit: $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am asked to solve following limit problem:

> $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$

It is pretty straightforward using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):

Since
$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = \frac{0}{0}$$
Then we take derivative of the numerator and denominator, getting:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos x}{1} =1$$

However, I would like to know whether there is a way to solve the limit problem above *without* L'Hôpital's rule. Is there?

Comment: Do you  know that $\sin \, x$ has a Taylor series expansion around $0$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, unfortunately, no.

Comment: Yes, that can be proved without L'Hopital. In fact you'd better, since that limit is usually what you need to find the derivative of $\sin$ in the first place. So using L'Hopital is circular resoning.

Comment: @Nelver: A Google search on "limit sinx/x" yields a number of links to proofs.

Comment: @Nelver: A search of Math.SE for "[proof limit sin x/x](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=proof+limit+sin+x%2Fx)" yields almost a thousand results. (Not all are specifically about this limit, of course.) I suspect you can find something useful among them.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the proof in any calculus textbook.  Or, here, for instance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Second_example

Comment: +1, although usually link only answers are discouraged on MSE.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know!